# What are common ways to distinguish between local minima and long run-time in hyperparamteer optimization

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, neural-networks

I'm using Bayesian optimization for a pretty cost expensive function in the context of neural networks in order to optimize hyperparameters for the neural net.

Is there a general, quantitative way to distinguish between becoming stuck in a local minimum in the optimization or just long running time of the process?

Comment: not a program-optimization question (mentioned in tags) :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, no.  Perhaps here is only one unique input that makes the function produce an enormously negative output; or perhaps there is none.  You can't tell the two apart without having examined a large fraction of all possible inputs to the function.